# Elasticsearch - Create field using script if doesn't exist

Tags: elasticsearch, field

Is there a way to dynamically add fields using scripts? I am running a script that checks whether a field exists. If not then creates it.

I'm trying out:

```
script: 'if (ctx._source.attending == null) { ctx._source.attending = { events: newField } } else if (ctx._source.attending.events == null) { ctx._source.attending.events = newField } else { ctx._source.attending.events += newField }'
```

Except unless I have a field in my _source explicitly named `attending` in my case, I get:

```
[Error: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script];
nested: PropertyAccessException[
    [Error: could not access: attending; in class: java.util.LinkedHashMap]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To check whether a field exists use the `ctx._source.containsKey` function, e.g.:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/myindex/message/1/_update" -d'
{
   "script": "if (!ctx._source.containsKey(\"attending\")) { ctx._source.attending = newField }",
   "params" : {"newField" : "blue" },
   "myfield": "data"
}'
```

Comment: Thanks will test this out when I get a chance. Is there a site with all the methods like `contains` and `containsKey`? If I knew where to look I would tried them.

Comment: I'm not aware of any single resource - my info comes from a variety of forums. When I ran into this problem, I eventually decided to store the fields in a separate child document - this seems more robust and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider if it's really necessary to see if the field exists at all.  Just apply the new mapping to ES and it will add it if it's required and do nothing if it already exists.

Our system re-applies the mappings on every application startup.

Comment: The field exists in the mapping, but it would throw the error regardless

Comment: If it was a simple field - then yes, **upsert** would work. However this looks like an array of values, the script needs to add to the array if it exists or create it if it doesn't.